# Get the updated document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to get the `_id` (the Mongo ObjectID) of updated document. For this I want to get the updated document. How can I get it?

I tried this:

```
...
collection.update(oldData, newData, function(err, doc) {
    console.log(docs); // This prints "1" in console. So, it's not a document.
    if (err) { return callback(err); }
    callback(null, doc);
});
...
```

Can I get it without finding a document by newData/oldData?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `.update()`, I think you want to use [`.findAndModify()`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-and-modify).

An update can update multiple documents, and the second argument of its callback is the number of updated documents (in your case, 1).

With `findAndModify`, you can update exactly one document (read the documentation on exactly how it differs from `update`), and the updated document will be passed to the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

In nodejs API solution is to set: {returnOriginal: false}.

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        whereObj,
        updateObj,
        {returnOriginal: false});
```

according to documentation:
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate