# How to return full document in a MongoDB update in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use the [update option](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update) `{ fullResult: true }` option in a MongoDB.

```
collection.update(query, payload, { fullResult: true }, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

While it does change the value of result, I'm not getting back the document. Instead, I'm getting back:

```
[ { updatedExisting: true,
    n: 1,
    lastOp: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1403025407 },
    connectionId: 510045,
    err: null,
    ok: 1 } ]
```

Is there something else I should be doing in order to get back to the updated document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the updated document in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333343/get-the-updated-document-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`findAndModify`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findAndModify):

```
collection.findAndModify(query,[['_id',1]],payload,{new:true},function(err,result) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.warn(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

The `new` option will return the *updated* document when set to `true`. If set to `false`, it will return the old document *before* update.

`findAndModify` also requires a *sort* parameter. If sorting is not important, then sorting on *_id* will be fine, but try to sort on something indexed.

---

Using `fullResult` with `update` does not do what you think. I agree, the docs are a bit confusing. Let the Node.js driver source speak for itself at [/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:568-572](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js#L568)

```
568      if(fullResult) return callback(null, result);
569      // Backward compatibility format
570      var r = backWardsCompatibiltyResults(result, 'update');
571      // Return the results for a whole batch
572      callback(null, r.n, r)
```

Regardless if `fullResult` is used, the `result` object is returned rather than a list of documents. The `result` object is what is returned from the raw db command via `db.command`. In the case when `fullResult` *is* used, it will return the raw unmodified result object - but still not documents.

Comment: It works as documented---it returns the full result document, that is, the document reporting on the update operation. The problem is that the full result document does not include the updated document, which is what you want.